# Reachibility between first and last layer in grid graph in logspace

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, turing-machines, space-complexity

I am trying to prove that there exists logspace deterministic Turing machine that check if exists path between first row and last row in grid graph. Grid graph is matrix of $0s$ and $1s$, the undirected edge exists between two $0s$  or $1s$ - one the left, right, up, down.   Path can contains only $0s$ or only $1s$.

For example in following graph there exists such path:

```
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
```

For following there is no such path

```
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
```

How to prove it ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL_(complexity)

Comment: Being honestly I don't know where are you going. At the bottom of your link: `It is also now known that a problem is in L if and only if it is log-space reducible to USTCON.` Oh, yes. I can reduce my problem in logspace: We should remember only two counters (2logn) and try to each possibility of nodes in first and last layer (it gives $O(n^2)$ possiblities, every of them we check one by one, so we use only logspace memory to remember two counters.  However, I am not sure if you meant this thing that I described above.

Answer (score 2):

I can't post a comment, which would be more appropriate:

Reingold's result gives a logspace algorithm, but reachability on undirected grid graphs was show to be in $L$ by Blum and Kozen about 30 years prior:

M. Blum and D. Kozen. [On the power of the compass (or,
why mazes are easier to search than graphs).](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp651/papers/2015-01-Spring/04567972.pdf) In IEEE Symposium
on Foundations of Computer Science (FOCS), pages
132–142, 1978.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an instance of [USTCON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL_(complexity)), which is known to be solvable in log space, thanks to a result of Omer Reingold:

[Undirected connectivity in log-space](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4b07/94ae3788df1851bdc4c7024764b99cd27f46.pdf).  Omer Reingold.  Journal of the ACM, vol 55 no 4, Sept 2008.

Thus, that paper describes how to build a logspace deterministic Turing machine that does what you want.

Comment: I think that your proposition here is overkill here. Lets note that our graph is special (grid). Moreover, we are looking for path between layers. Of course, I understand that using your paper it is solved immediately.